# Flutter Firestore Role Based Security Rules

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to determine if a specified field `role` in my user's collection is the one being used within the app. I have simulated this rule like below image in the rules section:[image]

I am trying to access the `Admin` field of the user collection in this image and check in the rules to allow creating a new product if the user is admin or superuser(can create admin users). Image below:

[image]

The rule simulation seems to fail, is there a proper way to access this field in security rules(see both images) or to set up the database properly? The fields were set in a form using radio buttons?

Overall desired task is to allow only certain sections of the app database to be accessed and/or manipulated by my users and also within the app itself, is there a way to query these fields and render the UI and interactions conditionally, to avoid the whole security rules thing?

The superuser is in the owner's collection, omitted for brevity and only one document in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is checking documents in your "projects" collection, but your screenshot is showing contents of doucments in the "users" collection.  So, there is obviously a mismatch here.

If you want to allow access to a document using the contents of another document, you will need to [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) the other document, then check it for the data you're looking for.  An example of this is provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).  What you will need to do is `get()` the user document for the currently authenticated user, then check that document's role field.  It will look something more like this:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role
```

Comment: Wow, clear pointers there but how do I access the RHS of the 'get' to know if it's Admin, Sales, etc? Equality sign is not needed or you can please edit the rule for me, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  The expression I showed can be compared to a string just like you're doing now, and as shown in the docs.

Comment: Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [24], column [23]. Type error. Received: [string] Expected: [bool]. It shows this error, when I put this in the function, can that function return a bool since the user can be either of Sales, Accounts, Admin or SuperUser?

Comment: Is there a viable solution using custom claims on creating the users?

Comment: The simulation works only after I equalise the RHS to a string role like == ''. Thanks for the answer, should have posted this earlier.

Comment: You should use Custom Claims, made specifically for this use case. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs

Is a server-side update on the user object, so no-one can interfere with it (admin SDK).
It can be triggered on user create/update.